# running an application on Google glasses

Tags: android, google-glass

Can I run any android application on google glasses? If Its possible please what i should change on my code to make it work on google glasses? I have big product and its work in all mobiles but i need to connect the glasses with it to display specific thing on google glasses. So How i can do it if possible?

For example: I test this app on my phone and its work for live stream, can i change part of code to make it work on google glass ?

https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/gocoder-sdk-samples-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
```

and

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 19
```

Google Glass depends on API Version 19, so you have to download SDK API 19 and GDK API 19.